# Checking a list of domain names to see if they've expired using client-side code

Tags: client-side, whois

I have a list of domain names. I can get this list in multiple formats, such as XML, HTML, CSV etc.

I want to be able to use client-side code to check if the domain names in the list have expired.

Does anyone have any suggestion how that could be done? I have seen various links to the WhoISXML API in other stackoverflow questions, but i require the service to be free.

Any ideas if this is even doable?

Answer (score 0):

There are several client side libraries. If you use Linux, give the [Linux whois library](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=whois) a try.

I'm also the maintainer of a [whois library](http://www.ruby-whois.org/), written in the Ruby programming language.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately i'm running a windows environment. Do you have anything that might be javascript based?